# raise with no argument

Tags: python, exception

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) for the raise statement with no arguments says

> If no expressions are present, raise re-raises the last exception that was active in the current scope.

I used to think that meant that the current function had to be executing an `except` clause. After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000985/how-do-i-get-the-line-number-for-a-logging-typeerror-of-not-all-arguments-conve) and experimenting a little, I think it means that any function on the stack has to be executing an `except` clause, but I'm not sure. Also, I've realized I have no idea how the stack trace works with a no-arg raise:

```
def f():
  try:
    raise Exception
  except:
    g()

def g():
  raise

f()
```

produces

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo", line 10, in <module>
    f()
  File "foo", line 5, in f
    g()
  File "foo", line 3, in f
    raise Exception
Exception
```

That doesn't look like the stack at the time of the initial raise, or the stack at the time of the re-raise, or the concatenation of both stacks, or anything I can make sense of.

Am I right about a no-arg raise looking for any function on the stack executing an `except` clause? Also, how does the stack trace work on a reraise?

Comment: It's worth noting that all of this stuff was cleaned up—and much better documented—in Python 3.x. So, you might do a lot better to look at 3.3 than 2.7. (IIRC, the wording for `raise` itself isn't much better, but the concept of "active exception" is actually defined somewhere or other, so you just have to search for it instead of trying to guess its meaning…)

Comment: raise NameError('Any text')

Answer (score 45):

When you `raise` without arguments, the interpreter looks for the *last* exception raised *and handled*. It then acts the same as if you used `raise` with the most recent exception type, value and traceback.

This is stored in the interpreter state for the current thread, and the same information can be retrieved using [`sys.exc_info()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info). By 'handled' I mean that an except clause caught the exception. Quoting the [`try` statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> Before an except clause’s suite is executed, details about the exception are assigned to three variables in the `sys` module: `sys.exc_type` receives the object identifying the exception; `sys.exc_value` receives the exception’s parameter; `sys.exc_traceback` receives a traceback object (see section [The standard type hierarchy](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#types) identifying the point in the program where the exception occurred. These details are also available through the `sys.exc_info()` function, which returns a tuple `(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)`.

See the [implemenation notes](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/addd9210816b/Python/ceval.c#l3304) in the Python evaluation loop (C code), specifically:

> The second
>     bullet was for backwards compatibility: it was (and is) common to
>     have a function that is called when an exception is caught, and to
>     have that function access the caught exception via sys.exc_ZZZ.
>     (Example: traceback.print_exc()).

The traceback reflects how you came to the re-raise accurately. It is the current stack (line 10 calling `f()`, line 5 calling `g()`) plus the *original* location of the exception raised: line 3.

Answer (score 14):

It turns out Python uses a surprising way of building tracebacks. Rather than building the whole stack trace on exception creation ([like Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#fillInStackTrace--)) or when an exception is raised (like I used to think), Python builds up a partial traceback one frame at a time as the exception bubbles up.

[Every time an exception bubbles up to a new stack frame, as well as when an exception is raised with the one-argument form of `raise`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Python/ceval.c#L3344) (or the two-argument form, on Python 2), the Python bytecode interpreter loop executes [`PyTraceback_Here`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Python/traceback.c#L229) to add a new head to the linked list of traceback objects representing the stack trace. (0-argument `raise`, and 3-argument `raise` on Python 2, skip this step.)

Python maintains a per-thread stack of exceptions (and tracebacks) suspended by `except` and `finally` blocks that haven't finished executing. 0-argument `raise` [restores](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Python/ceval.c#L3984) the exception (and traceback) represented by the top entry on this stack, even if the `except` or `finally` is in a different function.

When `f` executes its `raise`:

```
raise Exception
```

Python builds a traceback corresponding to just that line:

```
  File "foo", line 3, in f
    raise Exception
```

When `g` executes 0-argument `raise`, this traceback is restored, but no entry is added for the 0-argument `raise` line.

Afterwards, as the exception bubbles up through the rest of the stack, entries for the `g()` and `f()` calls are added to the stack trace, resulting in the final stack trace that gets displayed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo", line 10, in <module>
    f()
  File "foo", line 5, in f
    g()
  File "foo", line 3, in f
    raise Exception
Exception
```

Answer (score -2):

The following piece of code might help you understand how the raise keyword works:

```
def fun(n):
    try:
        return 0 / n
    except:
        print('an exception raised:')
        raise

try:
    fun(0)
except:
    print('cannot divide by zero')

try:
    fun('0')
except:
    print('cannot divide by a string')
```