# Difference between "raise" and "raise e"?

Tags: python, exception

In python, is there a difference between `raise` and `raise e` in an except block?

`dis` is showing me different results, but I don't know what it means.

What's the end behavior of both?

```
import dis
def a():
    try:
        raise Exception()
    except Exception as e:
        raise


def b():
    try:
        raise Exception()
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

dis.dis(a)
# OUT:   4           0 SETUP_EXCEPT            13 (to 16)
# OUT:   5           3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Exception)
# OUT:               6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
# OUT:               9 RAISE_VARARGS            1
# OUT:              12 POP_BLOCK           
# OUT:              13 JUMP_FORWARD            22 (to 38)
# OUT:   6     >>   16 DUP_TOP             
# OUT:              17 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Exception)
# OUT:              20 COMPARE_OP              10 (exception match)
# OUT:              23 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       37
# OUT:              26 POP_TOP             
# OUT:              27 STORE_FAST               0 (e)
# OUT:              30 POP_TOP             
# OUT:   7          31 RAISE_VARARGS            0
# OUT:              34 JUMP_FORWARD             1 (to 38)
# OUT:         >>   37 END_FINALLY         
# OUT:         >>   38 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
# OUT:              41 RETURN_VALUE        
dis.dis(b)
# OUT:   4           0 SETUP_EXCEPT            13 (to 16)
# OUT:   5           3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Exception)
# OUT:               6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
# OUT:               9 RAISE_VARARGS            1
# OUT:              12 POP_BLOCK           
# OUT:              13 JUMP_FORWARD            25 (to 41)
# OUT:   6     >>   16 DUP_TOP             
# OUT:              17 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Exception)
# OUT:              20 COMPARE_OP              10 (exception match)
# OUT:              23 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       40
# OUT:              26 POP_TOP             
# OUT:              27 STORE_FAST               0 (e)
# OUT:              30 POP_TOP             
# OUT:   7          31 LOAD_FAST                0 (e)
# OUT:              34 RAISE_VARARGS            1
# OUT:              37 JUMP_FORWARD             1 (to 41)
# OUT:         >>   40 END_FINALLY         
# OUT:         >>   41 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
# OUT:              44 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [raise with no argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001721/raise-with-no-argument)

Comment: @Jérôme I don't think this is a duplicate of that. This question is about the difference between no-arg and with-arg versions in this specific code sample. That question is about how no-arg works generally. They're related but not duplicate

Comment: Yes, and the accepted answer is interesting precisely for this reason. If there is a way to unflag a question, I'll do it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no difference in this case. `raise` without arguments [will always raise the last exception thrown](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) (which is also accessible with `sys.exc_info()`).

The reason the bytecode is different is because Python is a dynamic language and the interpreter doesn't really "know" that `e` refers to the (unmodified) exception that is currently being handled. But this may not always be the case, consider:

```
try:
    raise Exception()
except Exception as e:
    if foo():
        e = OtherException()
    raise e
```

What is `e` now? There is no way to tell when compiling the bytecode (only when actually *running* the program).

In simple examples like yours, it might be possible for the Python interpreter to "optimize" the bytecode, but so far no one has done this. And why should they? It's a micro-optimization at best and may still break in subtle ways in obscure conditions. There is a lot of other fruit that is hanging a lot lower than this and is more nutritious to boot ;-)

Comment: [...] _will always raise the last exception thrown_ - No it won't. It raises the current or active exception which is not necessary the last one thrown. It can be seen easily with the nested `try/except` block (too long to provide it here). I'm sure you meant that but your statement is semantically incorrect and may confuse IMHO.

Answer (score 40):

There is a difference in the backtraces that the two forms generate. The difference is different in Python 2 and 3.

Using `raise`:

```
try:
   int("hello")
except ValueError as e:
   raise
```

The code gives the following backtrace in Python 2 or Python 3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 2, in <module>
    int("hello")
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello'
```

Using `raise e`:

```
try:
   int("hello")
except ValueError as e:
   raise e
```

The code gives the following backtrace in Python 2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise e
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello'
```

The code gives the following backtrace in Python 3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise e
  File "myfile.py", line 2, in <module>
    int("hello")
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello'
```

In Python 2:

In the `raise` case, the original source of the exception is quoted in the backtrace. In the `raise e` case, the traceback references the `raise e` line not the original cause. Therefore, I recommend always using `raise` rather than `raise e`.

In Python 3:

The original source of the exception is always quoted. The difference is whether the `raise`/`raise e` line is also quoted. It depends on one's taste and the context of the `raise`.

Comment: The behaviour you're describing is true of Python 2, but not Python 3. In Python 3, `raise e` does not swallow the original source and actually shows strictly *more* information in this case.

Comment: This is a very important point. I've spent way too much time to trace the real source of error due to `raise e`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MarkAmery. I was almost referring this to my fellow colleague on Python 3 project.

Comment: The edit to change this answer to only talk about Python 2 is (1) incomplete: Python 3 isn't mentioned, so a reader will be like "what about Python 3" (2) misleading: there is still a difference in Python 3. I'll make another edit to address this.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to clear the "last exception" (i.e. the result of `sys.exc_info()`) info with `sys.exc_clear()`. For instance, this would happen if the catch block called a function `foo()`, which itself has special error handling.

In that case, `raise` with and without an argument would mean diffent things. `raise e` would still have a reference to the exception caught a few lines above, while the `raise` shorthand would try to raise `None`, which is an error.