# re-raise exception in Python

Tags: python, exception, raise

In a very well written and awesome book by Robert Smallshire and Austin Bingham there is the following code:

```py
def convert(s):
    """Convert a string to an integer."""
    try:
        return int(s)
    except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
        print("Conversion error: {}".format(str(e)), file=sys.stderr)
        raise
```

after that, the author has included the following string_log function

```py
def string_log(s):
    v = convert(s)
    return log(v)
```

and the output of `string_log('ouch')` is as follow

I am not able to understand what raise statement exactly works?

Also, the author says that the code where the first function outputs negative error code of -1  in case of `ValueError` and `TypeError` i.e the first function would be as follow

```py
import sys

def convert(s):
    """Convert a string to an integer."""
    try:
        return int(s)
    except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
        print("Conversion error: {}".format(str(e)), file=sys.stderr)
        return -1
```

and than if we run the following (without any change made `string_log()`) is
`string_log('cat')`

Is unpythonic but why?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: The _title_ of the book ("The Python Apprentice"?) would be far more useful than your review.

Comment: Are you asking what `raise` with no argument does, or are you asking why raising an exception is preferred over returning a special value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [raise with no argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001721/raise-with-no-argument)

Answer (score 1):

If `convert` returns `-1` on an error, then you have to explicitly check for that to avoid having `string_log` return `-1` as well. Just like `string_log` is expecting `convert` to return a valid string, so might the caller. Letting `-1` propagate can go undetected for a long time, and once an error *does* occur, it's not clear what the source of the error was.

With an exception, `string_log` doesn't return if it doesn't catch the exception; the exception continues up the call stack until it is caught, or the interpreter exits with a traceback. That traceback will show *exactly* where the exception originates.

---

`raise` with no argument simply raises the most recent exception, without having to write something like

```
except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
    print("Conversion error: {}".format(str(e)), file=sys.stderr)
    raise e
```

Here, you are using `e` in the call to `print` anyway, but if you didn't, you could write

```
except (ValueError, TypeError):
    print("Something bad happened!")
    raise
```

without having to bind the exception to an explicit name.